# Winter Bash 2018 doesn't want to Let Me Go

Tags: bug, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

Everytime I try to opt-out, I get this error message:

[image: An error occurred while opting out - please try again]

This is what I get in the console:

[image: Error 404 for https://meta.stackexchange.com/winter-bash/opt-out]

And it responds with the following:

[image: {"ErrorMessage":"failed to opt out of winter bash"}]

I tried, again and again and again.

This happens accross the whole StackOverflow (StackExchange?) network.

---

Edit: It works! For now?

[image: Bye Winter Bash 2018!]

Seems to have been fixed by what was done in: [Winter Bash 2018 icon disappeared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319915/winter-bash-2018-icon-disappeared)

On the [following comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319915/winter-bash-2018-icon-disappeared#comment1047866_319915):

[image: Comment by balpha♦]

Comment: Welcome to Hatel California ... you can check out anytime, but you can never leave.

Comment: @Glorfindel Don't you mean... "**Hat**el California"?

Comment: Looks like it was the same [last year too](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360588/winter-bash-opt-out-doesnt-work) and fixed after 7 hours.

Comment: Well, looks like it is a plot to keep us all using Winter Bash :(

Comment: [Happy now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319915/winter-bash-2018-icon-disappeared)? ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Not really, still can't opt-out :(

Comment: Nah, I meant by that that now it's not working for everyone.