# Winter Bash 2018 icon disappeared

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2018

After I clicked on the Winter Bash icon, instead of showing the hats notification screen the icon just dissappeared:

[image]

Now it's missing on all the StackExchange sites.

If that matters, the icon showed a number on it (one new hat) before I clicked on it.
Also I'm sure I didn't click the "I hate hats" link at the bottom of the Winter Bash notification screen.

Comment: I've noticed that this happens sometimes, but, if you give it time, it should show up  after almost 30 seconds.

Comment: I have disabled winterbash for anonymous users on Stack Overflow for now to decrease the number of connections, that seems to have relieved things. Will keep you posted.

Comment: @balpha Seems like it also fixed https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319914/winter-bash-2018-doesnt-want-to-let-me-go

Comment: Anonymous Stack Overflow users see hats again now.